# Dialog with a Spinner + orientation change

Tags: android, dialog, spinner

I have a Dialog with a Spinner. This is a managed dialog (ie I use `showDailog(DIALOG_ID)` to show it).

If I click on the Spinner there are 2 dialogs now - the main dialog and the Spinner popup.
After screen orientation it crashes. I can see 2 exceptions in LogCat, the first is WindowLeaked and the second IlleagalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager.

I guess this is a bug in Android, but is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: It would be a good idea to post your code and the log.

Answer (score 2):

Also struggled with this and wrote down my experiences regarding progress dialogs and orientation changes [on this blog post](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/14/handling-progress-dialogs-and-screen-orientation-changes/).

Required a lot of code plumbing to do it right (the official Android way to handle config and orientation changes), or a simple attribute on the activity in the manifest as a "workaround" without code changes.

Comment: I think that my problem is something different. I use only the main thread.